# No response from update where value is includes an ampersand

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I am working on Node and using oracle-db module.

I am trying to run this block through `connection.Execute(...)`:

```
BEGIN
Update emp set Firstname ='name1' where empID=('123','ui&uiu');
Update dep set Location ='Hyderabad' where depID in('132&ny&Y' , 'uiou89')
END;
```

Service is not returning anything and just stuck.

From searching I learned that I need to run `set define OFF` but when I include that line in the block it throws an error. So please guide me how can I set this.

Note: I do not want to use employee ID or department ID as parameters as I need to loop through for every parameter value.

Comment: `set define off` is a SQL\*Plus client command so don't try to use that - in PL/SQL, or at all in Node. The `&` is also specific to SQL\*Plus and related clients, and seems to be a coincidence here. If it isn't returning then the first thing I'd look for is rows in that table being locked by uncommitted changes in another session. Did you insert new data or try the update manually through a different client, for instance, and not commit or rollback that change?

Comment: Yes am trying to update the table and am sure its not locked by any other session..
my problem here to is to send data with escape characters like "&" and update the db which is not happening....

Comment: What do you mean by 'escape characters' though? The `&` is used for substitution variables, but as I already said that's client specific, and won't apply to Node. Why do you think those are the problem? (Also your first update is wrong - does your real code have `=` or `like`, as it will error as-is with `=`...)

Comment: You should be getting an error - maybe you've masked it somehow. It's impossible to say as you've not really shown us your code. But this doesn't make sense: `where empID=('123','ui&uiu');`

Comment: `'&'` is not special in node-oracledb, but you should still use bind variables unless the values never change.  Review documentation such as https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlproc and https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#inbind and https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#sqlwherein